# Convert IDictionary<string, object> to class

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I have a question. How to convert `IDictionary<string, object>` to class? As well as the create user account.

```
WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount(UserName, Password, new { eny = 0 , eny2 = "sas"});
```

And I have

```
void Create(String name, IDictionary<string, object> values)) {...}
```

and class

```
 class test {
    String name,
    int eny,
    int eny2
  }
```

I want to have a object test with data from dictionary.

Comment: Not sure with the way this is worded, but are you asking 2 questions?  Please try to explain yourself better.  What exactly are you asking and what class do you want to convert your `IDictionary<>` too?

Comment: My guess: the OP wants to create and/or instantiate a class (important to know which), where the properties are created/filled from a dictionary (key=property name, value=property value).

Answer (score 37, accepted):

I'll make a guess

```
Dictionary<string, object> values = new Dictionary<string, object>()
{
    {"Name","Joe"},{"Id",123}
};

var test = GetObject<TestClass>(values);
```

---

```
class TestClass
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

---

```
T GetObject<T>(Dictionary<string,object> dict)
{
    Type type = typeof(T);
    var obj = Activator.CreateInstance(type);

    foreach (var kv in dict)
    {
        type.GetProperty(kv.Key).SetValue(obj, kv.Value);
    }
    return (T)obj;
}
```

Comment: Can't we use deserialization (for example dictionary->Json->Deserialize to specific class) in this case ? And will It be faster, what do you think ?

Comment: Can't get it to work. I get for the kv.Key that I know is valid, a null. I can take dict["data"] (data is the key) and see the Json clearly. But it is 80 of the type I want so I should get a list of these. Or at least 1 of them.

type.GetProperty(kv.Key) returns a null. kv.Key is "data".  I can take dict[kv.Key] in the immediate window and get the Json string, which I want to cast into a list of objects.

So, my T needs to be List<T> and return needs to be 

return (List<T>)obj

but if GetProperty is returning NULL I can't get there.