# Querying abstract models in dapper

Tags: c#, inheritance, dapper, table-per-hierarchy

I'm using Table Per Hierarchy database inheritance where columns for all derived types are in a single table. Each derived table is identified using a string Discriminator field that holds the name of the derived class:

```
---------------------
| tanimal           |
---------------------
| animalid          |
| discriminator     |
| furcolour         |
| feathercolour     |
---------------------

public abstract class Animal
{
    public int AnimalId { get; set; }
    public string Discriminator { get { return GetType().Name; } }
}

public class Bird : Animal
{
    public string FeatherColour { get; set; }
}

public class Dog : Animal
{
    public string FurColour { get; set; }
}
```

As expected, when retrieving this via Dapper's query method I receive `Instances of abstract classes cannot be created`. I would hope that this would return a list of Animal with their values being the respective derived types.

```
var animals = Connection.Query<Animal>("SELECT * FROM tanimal")
```

My attempts to add support for this have been unsuccessful. Before SqlMapper.cs::GetTypeDeserializer() is called if the type being passed in is an abstract class then I replace the type with the one returned in the following method:

```
static Type GetDerivedType(Type abstractType, IDataReader reader)
{
    var discriminator = abstractType.GetProperty("Discriminator");
    if (discriminator == null)
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Cannot create instance of abstract class " + abstractType.FullName + ". To allow dapper to map to a derived type, add a Discriminator field that stores the name of the derived type");

    return Type.GetType((string)reader["Discriminator"]);
}
```

However it looks like at this point the reader hasn't been opened so it fails with `Invalid attempt to read when no data is present`.

Is this the correct approach to take? Has there been any effort to support this elsewhere?

Comment: https://github.com/StackExchange/dapper-dot-net/issues/262

Answer (score 5):

You can make this work but it will be less efficient than using Dapper's default behaviour with separate tables.

`GetDeserializer` needs to be called for every row, which means it needs to happen inside `while (reader.Read())`

By modifying `QueryImpl<T>` you can achieve the result you want. Assuming you're getting the results with:

```
var results = connection.Query<Animal>("SELECT * FROM tanimal");
```

Then the beginning of the `try {}` block of `QueryImpl<T>` will be:

```
try
{
cmd = command.SetupCommand(cnn, info.ParamReader);

if (wasClosed) cnn.Open();

// We can't use SequentialAccess any more - this will have a performance hit.
reader = cmd.ExecuteReader(wasClosed ? CommandBehavior.CloseConnection : CommandBehavior.Default);
wasClosed = false; 

// You'll need to make sure your typePrefix is correct to your type's namespace
var assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
var typePrefix = assembly.GetName().Name + ".";

while (reader.Read())
{
    // This was already here
    if (reader.FieldCount == 0) //https://code.google.com/p/dapper-dot-net/issues/detail?id=57
        yield break;

    // This has been moved from outside the while
    int hash = GetColumnHash(reader);

    // Now we're creating a new DeserializerState for every row we read 
    // This can be made more efficient by caching and re-using for matching types
    var discriminator = reader["discriminator"].ToString();
    var convertToType = assembly.GetType(typePrefix + discriminator);

    var tuple = info.Deserializer = new DeserializerState(hash, GetDeserializer(convertToType, reader, 0, -1, false));
    if (command.AddToCache) SetQueryCache(identity, info);

    // The rest is the same as before except using our type in ChangeType
    var func = tuple.Func;

    object val = func(reader);
    if (val == null || val is T)
    {
        yield return (T)val;
    }
    else
    {
        yield return (T)Convert.ChangeType(val, convertToType, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    }
}
// The rest of this method is the same
```

This will make the method work only with the discriminator field, so you may want to create your own `QueryImpl<T>` if you need this to work normally with other queries. Also I can't guarantee this will work in every case, only tested with two rows, one of each type - but this should be a good starting point.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for this :) Even if I was using TPT inheritance with separate tables, you'd still have a problem querying abstract types. I've created an issue on github if you wanted to post this there too: https://github.com/StackExchange/dapper-dot-net/issues/262

Comment: Yes you'd still have a problem with the abstract types, and the performance hit with the above code may be negligible if you have a small dataset.

Answer (score 5):

I want to share my solution as well. Inputs:

C#

```
abstract class Stock {}
class Bond: Stock {}
class Equity : Stock {}
```

SQL

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Stocks] (
....some columns....
    [Descriminator] VARCHAR (100) NOT NULL,
);
```

In SQL I have a Descriminator column which determines C# type for each row "Equity" or "Bond". Basicaly, this is a standard implementation if Table-Per-Hierarchy strategy.

I used Dapper's paremeter-less Query syntax

```
connection.Query(sql);
```

to get a `dynamic` object which Dapper sees as DapperRow. Although DapperRow is a private class, it implements `IDictionary<string, object>.` String - name of a property, Object - properties value.

Function [Convert IDictionary<string, object> to class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13720039/convert-idictionarystring-object-to-class)  (strongly typed):

```
public static T GetObject<T>(IDictionary<string, object> dict)
{
    Type type = typeof(T);
    var obj = Activator.CreateInstance(type);

    foreach (var kv in dict)
    {
        type.GetProperty(kv.Key).SetValue(obj, kv.Value);
    }
    return (T)obj;
}
```

And Mapper between descriminator column and C# class:

```
public static Stock ConvertToStock(object value)
{
    var dapperRowProperties = value as IDictionary<string, object>;
    switch (dapperRowProperties["Descriminator"])
    {
        case "Bond":
            return GetObject<Bond>(dapperRowProperties);
        case "Stock":
            return GetObject<Stock>(dapperRowProperties);
        default:
            return null;
    }
}
```

Usage of convertor:

```
public Stock GetStock(int id)
{
    Stock stock;
    var sql = "select * from Stocks where Id = @id";
    using (var connection = ConnectionFactory.GetOpenConnection())
    {
        stock = connection.Query(sql, new { id }).Select(ConvertToStock).Single();
    }
    return stock;
}
```

Comment: +1 great thanks for this. Presumably this would be fairly inefficient when dealing with a large dataset but it's good to have something here all the same.

Answer (score 3):

Created generic dapper extension method to query class hierarchy per table.
Perhaps would be usefull for someone.

```
    public static async Task<IEnumerable<TValue>> QueryHierarchyAsync<TValue, TKey>(
        this IDbConnection connection,
        CommandDefinition command,
        string discriminator,
        Func<TKey, Type> typeProvider)
    {
        int discriminatorIndex = -1;
        var parsers = new Dictionary<TKey, Func<IDataReader, TValue>>();

        var result = new List<TValue>();

        using (var reader = await connection.ExecuteReaderAsync(command))
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                if (discriminatorIndex < 0) discriminatorIndex = reader.GetOrdinal(discriminator);
                var objectValue = reader.GetValue(discriminatorIndex);
                if (!(objectValue is TKey value))
                    throw new Exception($"Discriminator value is not assignable to '{typeof(TKey).Name}'");

                if (!parsers.TryGetValue(value, out var parser))
                {
                    var type = typeProvider(value);
                    if (type == null)
                        throw new Exception($"Type for discriminator value '{value}' was not found");

                    if (!typeof(TValue).IsAssignableFrom(type))
                        throw new Exception($"Type '{type.Name}' is not assignable from '{typeof(TValue).Name}'");

                    parser = reader.GetRowParser<TValue>(type);
                    parsers.Add(value, parser);
                }

                result.Add(parser(reader));
            }
        }

        return result;
    }
```

Comment: Can you add an example of how to call the method, specifically what the typeProvider looks like.

Answer (score 1):

**May 2022 : Updated with improved code with type-caching and optional base class.**

For a similar problem in EFCore - [How to Automatically Map TPH Derived Classes in EF Core?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65778874/how-to-automatically-map-tph-derived-classes-in-ef-core) , I came up with this extension method that gets the derived sub-classes of a (usually abstract) class.

```
public static Type[] GetDerivedTypes(this Type type, 
                                          string[] ignoreTypeNames = null, 
                                          bool includeBaseType = false, 
                                          Assembly otherAssembly = null)
{
   ignoreTypeNames = ignoreTypeNames ?? Array.Empty<string>();
   
   var assembly = otherAssembly ?? Assembly.GetAssembly(type);

   var types =  assembly
                .GetTypes()
                .Where (t => t.IsSubclassOf(type) && 
                       (!ignoreTypeNames?.Any(t.Name.Contains) ?? false) )
                .ToList();

   if (includeBaseType)
       types.Add(type);

   return types.OrderBy(o => o.Name).ToArray();
}
```

Given a list of sub-types derived from a base type, you can build a dictionary of all sub-type parsers for the base class. Here is an extension method that brings back the typed records for any sub-type without manually having to map them. For my rules engine, this was a much simpler solution.

```
public static List<T> MapSubClassesOf<T>( this IDataReader reader, 
                                               Assembly assembly,
                                               string discriminator = "Discriminator",  
                                               bool includeBaseType = false )
{
    var list                = new List<T>();
    var derivedTypes        = typeof(T).GetDerivedTypes(includeBaseType: includeBaseType, otherAssembly: assembly); 
    var parsers             = new Dictionary<string, Func<IDataReader, T>>();

    while (reader.Read())
    {
        string typeName = reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal(discriminator));

        if (!parsers.ContainsKey(typeName))
        {
            Type derivedType = derivedTypes.Where(w => w.Name == typeName).FirstOrDefault();

            if (derivedType != null)
            {
                parsers.Add(typeName, reader.GetRowParser<T>(derivedType));
            }
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception($"The type {typeName} does not exist in the database.");
        }

        if (parsers.TryGetValue(typeName, out Func<IDataReader, T> parser))
        {
            var subType = parser(reader);

            list.Add(subType);
        }
    }
    return list;
}
```

Here is the code to call it. It will throw the exception above if the Discriminator in the table does not exist in the derived classes.

```
string sql = @"SELECT SymbolRuleId, SortOrder, RuleGroup,
                      Discriminator, Description
               FROM   SymbolRules";

using (var reader = GetConnection().ExecuteReader(sql) )
{
    return reader.MapSubClassesOf<SymbolRule>();
}
```